# Refresh and Notify about related collection changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, entity-framework-6

I will try to simplify as much as possible so:

I have following EF6 entity:

```
public class ParentObject
{
     ICollection<ChildObject> Children {get; set ;}
}
```

I have ViewModel where is

```
ObservableCollection<ParentObject> ParentCollection { get; set; }
ParentObject SelectedParent { get; set; }
ChildObject SelectedChild { get; set; }
```

Also I have two ListViews

```
<ListView Name="lvParents" Margin="5,5,0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParent}">


<ListView Name="lvChildren" Margin="5,5,0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedParent.Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedChild}">
```

All EF6 Entities have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented,
Also my ViewModel has INotifyPropertyChanged Implemented.

Everything is working well, if I'm changing selected item in lvParents. Children in lvChildren are changing.

Once I delete the children, I cannot refresh the Children:
(item is deleted from DB, but cannot refresh just lvChildren.

Here is method I tried to use:

```
_dataContext.ChildrenObjects.Remove(SelectedChild);
_dataContext.SaveChanges();
SelectedParent.Children.Remove(SelectedChild);

//here the SelectedParent does not contain the value I removed but no way how to refresh the ItemsSource of lvChildren.

NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedChild");
NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParent.Children");
NotifyPropertyChanged("ParentCollection");
```

My question is, what is the correct way to bind depended (related) collections and refresh them after they are changed. Do I need overload the EF6 ICollection and create my own ObservableCollection ???
Is it enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, what is the correct way to bind depended (related) collections and refresh them after they are changed?

The Children property of the ParentObject should return an ObservableCollection:

```
public class ParentObject
{
    ObservableCollection<ChildObject> Children {get; set ;}
}
```

Then the ItemsSource will be automatically refreshed when you remove an item from the collection:

```
SelectedParent.Children.Remove(SelectedChild);
```

That would be the most "correct" way of implementing this according the MVVM design pattern.

Using and binding to auto-generated entity types "as-is" is rarely a good idea in WPF. You should bind to ObservableCollection<T> properties rather than ICollection<T> ones if you want to be able to dynamically modify your collections at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for answer. (ICollection) is genereated by EF6 for related associated objects in relations.

Comment: I know. And ICollection properties are not WPF "friendly".